# Can I programmatically find when my Azure technical support plan ends?

Tags: azure

When a technical support plan is purchased for Windows Azure it is usually time limited. Once it ends the subscription falls back to "Basic, billing only" support plan. It would be nice to be able to monitor the current support plan and know when it expires and issue warning in advance from inside a monitoring program or from inside a cloud service.

Is it possible to retrieve that data programmatically (perhaps with Management API)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a new Azure Billing API now available, announced Summer 2015.

More info here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available

Hope that helps! :)